# Intensity of ultrasound emitter

Tags: ultrasound

I do an extraction of fir tree needles in water. The endings of branches with needles (4400 pounds) is placed on three levels of net in cylindrical container (6.56 feet diameter, 6.5 feet high). For destruction of needles membranes and the extraction process intencification I'm going to use ultrasound. What power and intensity of ultrasound should I use for this quantity of fir tree needles?

Comment: Welcome to [physics.se]! I'm wondering if this is really a physics or rather a [biology.se] question...

Answer (score 1):

That is a very large amount of fir needles to disrupt. You will need an industrial ultrasound generator of roughly 500 watts output (minimum, very likely more) to manage that mass of stuff.

But long before I would buy such a machine (which will cost tens of thousands of dollars) I would perform a series of benchtop experiments using small ultrasound *cleaning baths* to see if the basic idea has merit. Only then would I try to scale up the process.

Note also that in extraction processes like this, it is very important to do a separation on the feedstock beforehand to remove all the branches & twigs which add significant mass to the charge but contain no extractibles. Otherwise you are wasting energy processing junk through your machine which could instead be substituted with more feedstock that has extractables in it.

For example, in extracting mint oil from harvested & dried mint bushes, 90% of the biomass going into the extractor is in the form of stems and stalks with no mint oil at all in them, and big savings in energy consumption can be realized by separating the *leaves* from the *dross* beforehand.